# Android openCV Sample Error: cannot find the -lopencv_java

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm just follow the [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html) to setup the android opencv and try to run the sample of face-detection.

But it had the errors as shown: 
[image: error msg]

I had google around but still can't find the solution. Any idea how to solve it?
I'm using ndk-r10, elipse juno 4.2, & opencv android 2.4.9

Answer (score 1):

which ndk-r10 are you using ? The one for 32-bit target, 64-bit target, or both ?

From your error I see a reference to `arm64-v8a` which is a 64-bit target, but the OpenCV SDK is only precompiled for `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, `mips` and `x86`.

If you want to compile your project for 64-bit Android targets, you'll need to recompile OpenCV first but I don't know if it's already supported yet.

Comment: I use the "android-ndk64-r10-windows-x86_64.zip" which is Windows 64-bit target. 
After that I try to use the "android-ndk-r9-windows-x86_64.zip" and this shown another error.

Comment: And for what target do you want to compile ? To restrict compilation to 32-bit targets for those OpenCV is already compiled, you can set `APP_ABI := all32` inside _Application.mk_